# How to retrieve the time format of different Region

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, time-format

I have changed the time in windows 8.1 o.s as control panel -> Regional -> Formats as Korean(Korea) -> location as Korea. 
I have wrote the below code to display the time according to the above settings.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

but still it was showing the Indian current format only.

Comment: What format do you expect? It should be `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: not fixed format. according to the system setting it should display.